# Cassandra manual pagination: exposing pageState to client (in nodeJS)

Tags: node.js, pagination, cassandra, cassandra-2.0

Is it safe to expose the pageState to a client? Is it linked to the original query,or can I potentially expose other data? In my current implementation the client can send anything as a pageState.

Long story:
I'm building a REST api on NodeJs and I get my data from a Cassandra cluster. Since the queries have pretty big results, I need to do some kind of pagination. I got manual pagination working, but in my current implementation I send the pageState to the client and it sends it back in order to get the next batch of results.

```
if(req.query.page) {
        options.pageState = new Buffer(req.query.page,'hex');   
};
client.eachRow(query, [], options, function (n, row) {
       arr.push(row);
       }, function (err, result) { 
             res.send({
                values: arr,
                next: result.pageState
             });
        });
```

The other idea would be to save it in some kind of cache, and send an id to the client. I would send that id between server and client, and the pageState couldn't be modified. Just wondering if that's overhead, or actually needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in the [pagination docs of the driver](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/nodejs-driver/3.5/features/paging/) (see footnote at the very bottom), the page state token can be manipulated to retrieve other results within the same column family, so it is not safe to expose it to the users.

You should not expose the page state as a clear text value, you should hash it.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that footnote. Thanks for pointing it out. The hash is a great idea, much better than what I had in mind.